# My ConcurrentHashmap's value type is List,how to make appending to that list thread safe?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, thread-safety

My class extends from ConcurrentHashmap[String,immutable.List[String]]

and it has 2 methods :

```
  def addEntry(key: String, newList: immutable.List[String]) = {
    ...
    //if key exist,appending the newList to the exist one 
    //otherwise set the newList as the value
  }

  def resetEntry(key: String): Unit = {
    this.remove(key)
  }
```

in order to make the addEntry method thread safe,I tried :

```
this.get(key).synchronized{
  //append or set here
}
```

but that will raise null pointer exception if key does not exist,and use putIfAbsent(key, new immutable.List()) before synchronize won't work cause after putIfAbsent and before goes into synchronized block,the key may be removed by resetEntry.

make addEntry and resetEntry both synchronized method will work but the lock is too large

So, what could I do?

ps.this post is similiar with [How to make updating BigDecimal within ConcurrentHashMap thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567596/how-to-make-updating-bigdecimal-within-concurrenthashmap-thread-safe) while plz help me figure out how to code other than general guide

--update--
checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/34309186/404145, solved this after almost 3+ years later.

Comment: @maasg still working on it,now I adopt Vint's method:instead of removing,I clear it.As for the too many keys issue,I thought maybe I can schedule another thread to lock the whole map to clean keys at a given interval.

Comment: @maasg by making use of ReadWriteLock, finally solve the problem, checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/34309186/404145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more than 3 years, I think now I can answer my question.

The original problem is:

I get a `ConcurrentHashMap[String, List]`, many threads are appending values to it, how can I make it thread-safe?

Make `addEntry()` synchronized will work, right?

```
synchronize(map.get(key)){
  map.append(key, value)
}
```

In most cases yes except when `map.get(key)` is null, which will cause NullPointerException.

So what about adding `map.putIfAbsent(key, new List)` like this:

```
map.putIfAbsent(key, new List)
synchronize(map.get(key)){
  map.append(key, value)
}
```

Better now, but if after `putIfAbsent()` another thread called `resetEntry()`, we will see NullPointerException again.

Make addEntry and resetEntry both synchronized method will work but the lock is too big.

So what about MapEntry Level Lock when appending and Map Level Lock when resetting?

Here comes the ReentrantReadWriteLock:
When calling `addEntry()`, we acquire a share lock of the map, that makes appending as concurrently as possible, and when calling `resetEntry()`, we acquire an exclusive lock to make sure that no other threads are changing the map at the same time.

The code looks like this:

```
class MyMap extends ConcurrentHashMap{
  val lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();  

  def addEntry(key: String, newList: immutable.List[String]) = {
    lock.readLock.lock()

    //if key exist,appending the newList to the exist one 
    //otherwise set the newList as the value
    this.putIfAbsent(key, new List())
    this(key).synchronized{
        this(key) += newList
    }

    lock.readLock.unlock()
  }

  def resetEntry(key: String, currentBatchSize: Int): Unit = {
    lock.writeLock.lock()

    this.remove(key)

    lock.writeLock.unlock()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the entry, can you simply clear it?  You can still use a synchronized list and ensure atomicity.

```
  def resetEntry(key: String, currentBatchSize: Int): Unit = {
    this.get(key).clear();
  }
```

This works with the assumption that each key has an entry.  For example if `this.get(key)==null` You would want to insert a new `sychronizedList` which should act as a clear as well.

Comment: but I have thousands of thousand keys,and that number will keep growing,so just clear the entry will cause the map get bigger and bigger.

Comment: Since remove+add is not an atomic instruction you would have to synchronize on the Map itself to ensure atomicity.  Are you certain that having the extra key + an empty list will consume too much memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a method inspired by the CAS (Compare and Swap) process:

(in pseudo-java-scala-code, as my Scala is still in its infancy)

```
def addEntry(key: String, newList: immutable.List[String]) = {
    val existing = putIfAbsent(key, newList); 
    if (existing != null) {
       synchronized(existing) {
           if (get(key) == existing) { // ask again for the value within the synchronized block to ensure consistence. This is the compare part of CAS
                return put(key,existing ++ newList); // Swap the old value by the new
           } else {
               throw new ConcurrentModificationException(); // how else mark failure?
           }
       }
    }
    return existing;
}
```

Comment: Also, an interesting gist by Viktor Klang on a multimap impl (so, a set iso a list as value) -> https://gist.github.com/566793